# Parse: fetch relation items with REST API

Tags: api, rest, parse-platform

In Parse I've two classes with a many-to-many relation, for example `items` and `categories`. I've created in the class `items` a relation with `categories` and all work fine with querying and updating. My problem is when I need to change the `items` relation with linked `categories`.

As far as I know, if I need to change the relation of `items` with `categories`, I first need to delete all `categories` relation with `RemoveRelation` and later re-add them with `AddRelation`. To do that I need to fetch all `categories` objectId from my `item`.

How can I do that with a REST API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have an item with objectId of `xyz` in your `Items` class. In that class you have a Relation field called `categories` which holds a list of objects from `Category` class. To get all the category objects from that relationship, you can do the following REST call using curl:

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxx"   -H "X-Parse-REST-API-  Key: xxx" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  
-G --data-urlencode 'where={"$relatedTo":{"object":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Items","objectId":"xyz"},
"key":"categories"}}' https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Category
```